# Many-to-many relationship SELECT issue

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a very annoying problem on the application I've been contracted to work in.

The database structure, **which I can't modify for compatibility reasons** is a mess. It's basically a *many-to-many-to-many-to-many-to-bang-your-head-on-the-desk relationship*. It goes like this:

**contact**

```
---------------------------
| contact_id | name | ... |
---------------------------
| 1          | foo  |     |
---------------------------
```

**metadefinition**

```
-----------------------------
| metadefinition_id | name  |
-----------------------------
| 1                 | title |
-----------------------------
| 2                 | job   |
-----------------------------
```

**contact_metadata**

```
----------------------------
| contact_id | metadata_id |
----------------------------
| 1          | 1           |
----------------------------
| 1          | 2           |
----------------------------
```

**metadata**

```
-------------------------------------------
| metadata_id | metadefinition_id | value |
-------------------------------------------
| 1           | 1                 | mrs   |
-------------------------------------------
| 2           | 2                 | coder |
-------------------------------------------
```

So, for a single contact, I want to search on all this and obtain something like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| contact_id | name | metadata.title | metadata.job |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1          | foo  | mrs            | coder        |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

So now what I've tried so far. I can fetch the list of `metadefinition` in advance, that's not really an issue. So I build a query like this:

```
SELECT contact.*,m1.value AS `metadata.title` FROM contact
   LEFT JOIN contact_metadata ON contact.contact_id = contact_metadata.contact_id
   LEFT JOIN metadata m1 ON contact_metadata.metadata_id = m1.metadata_id AND m1.metadefinition_id = 1
   GROUP BY contact_id
```

This works for a single `metadefinition`, I get something like this:

```
--------------------------------------
| contact_id | name | metadata.title |
--------------------------------------
| 1          | foo  | mrs            |
--------------------------------------
```

If I try with two, however:

```
SELECT contact.*,m1.value AS `metadata.title`,m2.value AS `metadata.job` FROM contact
   LEFT JOIN contact_metadata ON contact.contact_id = contact_metadata.contact_id
   LEFT JOIN metadata m1 ON contact_metadata.metadata_id = m1.metadata_id AND m1.metadefinition_id = 1
   LEFT JOIN metadata m2 ON contact_metadata.metadata_id = m2.metadata_id AND m2.metadefinition_id = 2
   GROUP BY contact_id
```

I get:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| contact_id | name | metadata.title | metadata.job |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1          | foo  | mrs            | NULL         |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

If I remove the GROUP BY clause, of course, I get:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| contact_id | name | metadata.title | metadata.job |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1          | foo  | mrs            | NULL         |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1          | foo  | NULL           | coder        |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

**I'm open to anything as long as the query times are relatively acceptable (considering the structure, if it takes 10 seconds for 100000 records it's better than nothing)**

Will it be temporary tables, stored procedures, I don't care, as long as I don't have to change the actual database structure.

Trust me, when it'll be the time to remodel, it'll be my pleasure to take this whole thing down.

Is there a solution to this, is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since MySQL doesn't directly support [pivot tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx), you are going to have to make views to manually create the pivots ([examples](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table)). Keep in mind though that there is nothing wrong with this data structure (see [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)). It is perfectly flexible, yet can be hard to work with in some instances.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to figure out what it is you're actually trying to do.  I don't see a problem with the table structure.  And those results look like I would expect them to.  What are you trying to represent in your results?

Comment: @Neil D: It seems you didn't read the entire question. All the information I have is there: DB structure, actual results, expected results. If you read carefully, you can clearly see that the result I get is not what I want. As for the DB structure, it is clearly overkill for what it's trying to do.

Comment: @netcoder: If you read the entire question you can clearly see that the expected results for the second query aren't there, you just have the results you actually got.

Comment: @Neil, he stuck the expected results in the middle of the question: `So, for a single contact, I want to search on all this and obtain something like this`

Comment: @netcoder, One man's "overkill" is another man's "not enough". There is no right or wrong here.

Comment: @Kevin Peno: I agree with your first statement. But still, it's wrong because flexibility was never required in the first place. If it was actually a requirement, I wouldn't rant about it. But this isn't the case, this is a classic example of *over-engineering*. ;-)

Comment: @netcoder: Sure, that is quite possible, but I'm at a disadvantage not knowing the requirements to argue either side. Thus my previous comment :)

Comment: @Kevin Peno: Fair enough. You're totally right. :)

Comment: Don't "bang-your-head-on-the-desk" and don't take this "whole thing" down. Not before you understand why it's done like that, at least. It's called normalization.

Comment: @netcoder my apologies I really didn't read that very carefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use a pair of correlated sub-queries. Something like

```
SELECT c.*
  ,( Select value from metadata m1 
       INNER JOIN contact_metadata cm 
       on cm.metadata_id = m1.metadata_id 
     WHERE m1.metadefinition_id = 1 
       AND cm.contact_id = c.contact_id )AS `metadata.title`
  ,( Select value from metadata m1 
       INNER JOIN contact_metadata cm 
       ON cm.metadata_id = m1.metadata_id 
     WHERE m1.metadefinition_id = 2 
       AND cm.contact_id = c.contact_id )AS `metadata.job`
FROM contact c
WHERE c.contact_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. Now I need to figure out how to make this work in Zend_Db... Ugh. At least that problem's fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to fetch each metadata item (title, job etc.) as a separate subquery, and then join on contact_id to bring these metadata items together for each contact. Like this:

```
SELECT contact.*, metadata_title, metadata_job FROM contact 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT contact_id,m.value AS `metadata_title` FROM contact_metadata 
   LEFT JOIN metadata m ON contact_metadata.metadata_id = m.metadata_id AND m.metadefinition_id = 1) metaTitle ON metaTitle.contact_id=contact.contact_id
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT contact_id,m.value AS `metadata_job` FROM contact_metadata 
   LEFT JOIN metadata m ON contact_metadata.metadata_id = m.metadata_id AND m.metadefinition_id = 2) metaJob ON (metaJob.contact_id=contact.contact_id)
```

If you want to allow for the possibility of a client not having a particular metadata item, use `LEFT JOINs` instead, as at present, the query will only return clients that have both a job and a title defined.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I've finally read the question properly, here's my two cents, for what's it's worth (no pun intended).

```
SELECT contact.contact_id, contact.name, m1.value AS 'metadata.title', m2.value AS 'metadata.job'     
FROM dbo.contact
INNER JOIN dbo.contact_metadata cm1 ON cm1.contact_id = cm1.contact_id
INNER JOIN dbo.metadata m1 ON cm1.metadata_id = m1.metadata_id AND m1.metadefinition_id = 1
INNER JOIN dbo.contact_metadata cm2 ON contact.contact_id = cm2.contact_id
INNER JOIN dbo.metadata m2 ON cm2.metadata_id = m2.metadata_id AND m2.metadefinition_id = 2
```